# whats wrong with the for loop in the list used?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to define a list using a `for` loop:

```
import numpy as np
# 2 input neurons , next 3 hidden , 5 hidden , 2 output neurons
layer_sizes = { 2,3,5,2 }
# for matrix shapes 3,2  5,3 and 2,5
weight_shapes = [{a,b} for a,b in zip(layer_sizes[1:],layer_sizes[:-1])]
#weight_shapes = [ {3,2},{5,3},{2,5}]
weights = [np.zeros(s) for s in weight_shapes]
print(weight_shapes)
print(weights)
```

But I kept getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\NNe2.py", line 5, in <module>
    weight_shapes = [{a,b} for a,b in zip(layer_sizes[1:],layer_sizes[:-1])]
TypeError: 'set' object is not subscriptable
```

I expect print statements to provide the content of the lists.

Comment: Use `tuple` or `list` in place of `set : {}`? So, replace all `{` with `(` or `[`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `layer_sizes` is the [set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)) `{2, 3, 5}`,
but your comment suggests you were hoping it would be a [list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list) of length 4,
as if it were declared in this way:

```
layer_sizes = [2, 3, 5, 2]
```